# Can not upload .apk to Google Play (cannot upload a test-only APK)

Tags: android, gradle, google-play

Using gradle plugin: com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3.
After generating signed .apk, I can not upload it to Google Play: Cannot upload a test-only APK. Nothing in build process was not change from previous version, moving to previous gradle version is impossible - a lot of functionality now are based on new libraries (like font, lambdas, etc.)

Is there some idea how to build .apk for Google Play with .alpha* libraries?

Comment: Is your APK signed?

Comment: @CedricMartens Yes, I made the same steps in previous version of libs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change line in module build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-O'
```

to:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use preview version in release version
As developer website says so you should edit your compileSdkVersion to earlier one

[image]